# flutter_map - Why the location is changing, and the map is not moving?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use flutter_map and geolocator packages for my app. I have built MainMap widget to manage the Stream from Geolocator(), and pass it to another widget. It's all fine, my marker is moving, when my location changes, but my map still stays in the same place. I don't know why the center property is not changing at all. _currentPosition values are good because they change properly in Text widget.

```
options: MapOptions(
            center: _currentPosition,
            zoom: 10,
            plugins: [
              MarkerClusterPlugin(),
            ],
          ),
```

```
Text('${_currentPosition.latitude}, ${_currentPosition.longitude}',),
```

Here's the whole code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map_marker_cluster/flutter_map_marker_cluster.dart';
import 'package:latlong/latlong.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class MainMap extends StatelessWidget {
  final locationOptions =
      LocationOptions(accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best, distanceFilter: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Geolocator().getPositionStream(locationOptions),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }
        return MainMapContent(position: snapshot.data);
      },
    );
  }
}

class MainMapContent extends StatefulWidget {
  final Position position;

  MainMapContent({this.position, Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainMapContentState createState() => _MainMapContentState();
}

class _MainMapContentState extends State<MainMapContent> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _currentPosition =
        LatLng(widget.position.latitude, widget.position.longitude);
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlutterMap(
          options: MapOptions(
            center: _currentPosition,
            zoom: 10,
            plugins: [
              MarkerClusterPlugin(),
            ],
          ),
          layers: [
            TileLayerOptions(
              urlTemplate: "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/"
                  "{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x.png?access_token={accessToken}",
              additionalOptions: {
                'accessToken':
                    '<redacted for security>',
                'id': 'mapbox.streets',
              },
            ),
            MarkerClusterLayerOptions(
              maxClusterRadius: 50,
              size: Size(40, 40),
              anchor: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.center),
              fitBoundsOptions: FitBoundsOptions(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
              ),
              markers: [
                Marker(
                  anchorPos: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.center),
                  height: 30,
                  width: 30,
                  point: _currentPosition,
                  builder: (ctx) => Container(
                    height: 40,
                    width: 40,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.account_circle,
                      color: Colors.black,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
              polygonOptions: PolygonOptions(
                borderColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                color: Colors.black12,
                borderStrokeWidth: 3,
              ),
              builder: (context, markers) {
                return FloatingActionButton(
                  child: Text(markers.length.toString()),
                  onPressed: null,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              Text(
                '${_currentPosition.latitude}, ${_currentPosition.longitude}',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Somebody can help me? I don't know what to do. I think is should work that way, but it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and for me the easiest way was to use https://github.com/igaurab/user_location_plugin for Flutter Maps. The plugin automatically moves the map so that the current location is always in the middle. You can also disable it in the settings (this was annoying for my application), but by default the plugin should meet your requirements.

Btw.: I don't think it's good to post your accesstoken. I use "https://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&hl=de&x=8&y=6&z=4" as Tile Provider, so my users have there typical Google Maps feeling and I don't need any accesstoken. Probably the google Tile Provider is also interesting for you.